# The time difference between what Postman presents and API-gateway logs

Tags: performance, postman, aws-api-gateway

I am testing a API endpoint via postman

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMxhv.png)

The transfer start time period is 1271.98ms which is a bit longer than I expected.

I check the Cloudwatch logs for this request, the integration latency for it is62ms.

[API-Gateway log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBH05.png)

Because this transfer start time period displayed by postman doesn't contain DNS lookup, TCP/SSL handshake. I am curious why there is such a difference due to the endpoint processing is quite fast.

I expect postman transfer start time period is the same as API-Gateway integration latency.

Comment: Did you find out why? I have this same issue now. Check if the client and server are in same region? If not, network latency might be at play. You can see this when you run ping to servers in same region vs server in farther region. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052158/is-significant-latency-introduced-by-api-gateway.